# Preventing instantaneous execution of this code?

Tags: recursion, widget, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm having trouble understanding how to update a widget in Tk to reflect an ongoing process. 
Basically, right now my program is to recursively scan a directory and is supposed to output each directory/file it finds to a text widget one at a time. My problem is that instead of doing this, the script finds all of the directories and then outputs everything all at once when it's done. Here's the code:

```
proc scan {{dir .}} {
global num_items_found vs_list ec_list

foreach i [lsort [glob -nocomplain -dir $dir *]] {
    if {[file type $i]=="directory"} {
        .main.body.log insert end "Checking $i\n";
        scan $i;
    } else {
        if {[string tolower [file tail $i]] eq "buildlog.htm"} {
            lappend vs_list $i;
            incr num_items_found;
            .main.body.log insert end "Found $i\n";
        } elseif {[file extension $i] eq ".log"} {
            lappend ec_list $i;
            incr num_items_found;
            .main.body.log insert end "Found $i\n";
        }
    } 
}

return;
}
```

I am also calling this proc in a different proc, in which I am also disabling a button prior to the scan and re-enabling it after; yet this doesn't work either. The script doesn't allow my widgets to update at all before the scan proc executes? How can I get the desired result?

Thanks!

Comment: You do not let the event loop run and do its work. Have a look at http://wiki.tcl.tk/946

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most display updates in Tk happen from the event loop. In your case, the event loop is not entered until after you finish the directory traversal. You might want to use the `update idletasks` command.

From the manual:

> The `update idletasks` command is useful in scripts where changes have been made to the application's state and you want those changes to appear on the display immediately, rather than waiting for the script to complete. Most display updates are performed as idle callbacks, so `update idletasks` will cause them to run. However, there are some kinds of updates that only happen in response to events, such as those triggered by window size changes; these updates will not occur in update idletasks.

Comment: Provided you take steps to avoid reentrancy problems, `update` is better, since it allows you to handle repaint requests from the OS. OTOH, you _have_ to be careful with it or you'll end up with unwanted recursive calls into your event handlers; it's [often considered harmful](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1255) for very good reason.

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback; very helpful.